# Controlling drag move with tap count in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch, drag

I have a custom button class..
I want to be able to control this button through tap counts..
When the user taps only once, the button will popup a comment box..
When the user taps twice or tap once and hold the button for more than 2 seconds, the button will begin to drag..
I added these lines to my custom button class to catch drag events..

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(dragBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(dragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(dragEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


-(void)dragBegan:(UIControl *)c withEvent:ev {
[delegate customDragBegan:c withEvent:ev];
```

I tried this function:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

};
```

But when touch ends, dragEnds won't fire.. I'm little messed up..

For now, I can drag buttons correctly.. Just need to figure out how to control that first attempt... 2 taps drag, 1 tap another function..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: (a little newbie but it solves my problem)
I use the touch events.. When touch begins I check the touch count.. If it's equal to 2 then I call my delegates custom drag function.. And set my isDraggable BOOL to Yes.. So in touch End function I can determine if I should call custom drag ended function in delegate..

I hope it will be helpful to someone like me..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touchSample = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
switch ([touchSample tapCount]) {
    case 1:
        isDraggable = NO;
        NSLog(@"SHOW COMMENT");
        break;
    case 2:
        isDraggable = YES;
        NSLog(@"START DRAG");
        [delegate customDragBegan:self withEvent:event];
        break;   
    default:

        break;
}


};
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if (isDraggable) {
    [delegate customDragMoving:self withEvent:event];
};


};

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

if (isDraggable) {
    [delegate customDragEnded:self withEvent:event];
};

};
```